# Getting error (json 514, 513)in addition to Incorrect type: expected string in the nodejs application on moralis?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, decentralized-applications, moralis

```
 "homepage": "https://github.com/000/Dapp-x#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "moralis": "^2.6.4"
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node index.js"
    },
```

Comment: Hi can you share more of your code and where this error is coming from exactly?

Comment: Hey Alex, this is a sample dapp mentioned on moralis website, I have just started testing this platform, here's the link : https://docs.moralis.io/docs/nodejs-dapp-from-scratch

Comment: I can't reproduce that error - how do you run the project (which command)? It looks like your error is TypeScript related yet your start script is just running it normally. The tutorial code isn't in TS so you will get errors. Can you try copying all the code at the bottom https://docs.moralis.io/docs/nodejs-dapp-from-scratch#all-done and then change the API key as well.

Comment: I'll check back. Tnks!!!